# How to change values in spesific cells after copying VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to change all the values in a workbook that is not active. All the values are listed in the same column.

In the code i'm first going to copy some specific cells, after copy them I want to set the value = 0 in cells C3:C19. My code looks like this:

```
Range("A3:D19").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

I then tried to used replace on C3:C19, this did not work.

Thanks :)

Comment: So you just need to put `0` in all the cells of worksheet and you don't know how ?

Comment: Give more context please. About how the data looks or where are you copying it to and change which values to 0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I copying from inactive workbooks, and there is one column i need to change. This would be C3:C19. After copying them they should be changed. The plan is to use this as a test to check if they have been updated until next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A3:D19").Copy
Worksheets(2).Range("A3:D19").Paste ' <~~ Do whatever else here
Worksheets(1).Range("C3:C19").Value = 0
```

Comment: When using the Range.("C3:C19").Value=0, it changes both values in the workbook I copy from and the one I paste it into. Do I need to paste before changing the values? I do it after.

Comment: You need to do it in the order I specified. If you change the value to 0 before you copy, you're copying the 0, not the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you could show some of your code.

```
Range("whatever") = 0
```